# Make use of 3rd party packages

Tags: ros, installation, dependencies, package, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys..
I am a bit new with ROS, and I am struggling with making use of a 3rd party package. namely [flir_ptu_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/flir_ptu_driver).

I am not sure how to even make use of it. I tried creating a workspace, and git clone it into the SRC file.  but when i performed catkin_make and catkin_make install I received error messages saying

> add the installation prefix of
> "serial" to  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "serial_DIR" to a directory containing
> one of the above files. if "serial"
> provides a separate development
> packages SDK, be sure it has been
> installed.

I am not sure what it means but hope some you guys could help guide through the setup phase of this ros stacks, or just in general.

I found one in the tutorial, but it seemed like it was more focused on a certain kind of stack, and not an "all-purpose" stack installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202896/make-use-of-3rd-party-packages./) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-11**:
Have you followed the introductory [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)? They should give you at least some more insight into how things work with pkgs.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-11**:
I understand your concern..
yes I have been followed the introductory tutorial, and I know the mistake must be something very silly.. i've tried so many different things.. That i think i might have mixed them together..
This how my workspace is here: http://tinyurl.com/q9v9w92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you are seeing tells you that `flir_ptu_driver` cannot find one of its dependencies, in this case the [serial](http://wiki.ros.org/serial) package.

Depending on what you actually intend to do, you have two options:

1. install the binary release of `flir_ptu_driver`: something like `sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-flir-ptu-driver` should work. All dependencies should also be automatically installed for you this way.
2. make sure you have all dependencies installed before trying to `catkin_make` the sources: you can do this with `rosdep`, like so (see also the rosdep [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/)):

   ```
   rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
   ```

after you have sourced the appropriate `setup.bash` for your ROS distro.

Invoking `catkin_make` should now succeed (provided `flir_pty_driver` declares all its dependencies correctly).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-11**:
installed the serial dependencies , and it works now..